# Access global pointer in another class

Tags: c++, pointers, global

I have defined globally a list in one class as a pointer:

class1.cpp

```
type list[1000];
type *p_list = list;
```

Now I want to use this list and put some values into it. This should happen in another class, in a method

class2.cpp

```
mousePressEvent_from_class_2()
{
    p_list[counter].x = pos().x(); 
}
```

But the compiler is telling me that it doesn't know p_list. How can I change that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler needs to know that `p_list` is declared elsewhere. Put the following in `class1.h` or in `class2.cpp` (at file scope).

```
extern type *p_list;
```

The definition of `type` must also be visible in `class2.cpp`. Make sure the definition is in a header file (class1.h) and class2.cpp `#include`s this header.